# Select newest records from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have three tables in mysql database:

**Flats** [id, section, title, description, rooms, price, updated]

**Houses** [id, section, title, description, rooms, price, updated]

**Lands** [id, section, title, description, area, price, updated]

I need to retrieve four newest records from all records in these tables in one query (id, title) and I don't know how to write query correctly. I've tried this:

```
    SELECT                                 
       flats.id, flats.title, houses.id, houses.title, lands.id, lands.title
    FROM 
       flats, houses, lands
    ORDER BY
       updated DESC
    LIMIT
       3
```

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Please clarify - do you want 4 records _in total_, or 4 records from each of the three tables?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want 4 records of total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `union all` operator to "concat" the results, and then use a `limit` clause to get the top four:

```
SELECT  id, title
FROM    (SELECT id, title, updated FROM flats
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id, title, updated FROM houses
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id, title, updated FROM lands) t
ORDER BY updated DESC
LIMIT    4
```

EDIT:
As pointed out by Michael and John in the comments, the subquery is redundant:

```
SELECT   id, title, updated FROM flats
UNION ALL
SELECT   id, title, updated FROM houses
UNION ALL
SELECT   id, title, updated FROM lands
ORDER BY updated DESC
LIMIT    4
```

Comment: The subquery shouldn't be necessary. The `ORDER BY/LIMIT` would be applied over the whole `UNION`.

Comment: Just remove the first select from.. Union syntax allows the order by and limit :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT                                 
   flats.id, flats.title, houses.id, houses.title, lands.id, lands.title
FROM 
   flats
CROSS JOIN houses
CROSS JOIN lands
ORDER BY
   updated DESC
LIMIT
   3
```

But this is not good tactics :D I guess, if you shuld do something like this

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL most common way to do that is to use `UNION` statement.

So, in your case:

`(SELECT id,title from flats ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 4)
UNION
(SELECT id,title from houses ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 4)
UNION
(SELECT id,title from lands ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 4);`

More info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html